# SQL injection with stored procedure name

Tags: url, sql-injection

I have a url with stored procedure name as parameter.

This is a sample url with parameter "MyStoredProcedure" as the stored procedure name. Is there a way that I can replace or execute some system inbuilt SPs or do any other hacking with this url?

http://mywebapp/arsys/BackChannel/?param=170%2FExpandMenu%2F13%2FSQLMenuOnOpen14%2Fmyserver%2Fmyconsoleapp14%2Fmyserver14%2FIR_MainConsole0%2F0%2F1%2F01%2F02%2F0%2F2%2F0%2F2%2F0%2F13%2F1%2F9%2F58000011015%2F1%2F10%2F**MyStoredProcedure**5%2F1%2F1%2F42%2F0%2F2%2F0%2F2%2F0%2F&sToken=TK6I-9RXH-1UQW-IILQ-8A31-AK21-YE01-IOXK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my white paper that introduced "SQL Injection anywhere - deliberate runtime error binary SQL injection". 
It might be helpful (depending on the DB type).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3_AmubjewYTMmY4MDRiNTAtYmVkMi00NGQ4LTg3NjEtY2ZlNTdiYjZlYzUy/view?ddrp=1&hl=en